# VBA: Declarar variáveis em linha

Tags: vba, sintaxe

Para declarar variáveis no `VBA`, eu sempre utilizei o seguinte método: todas as variáveis do mesmo tipo eu colocava em uma mesma linha e declarava o tipo delas apenas no final, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
Dim RngSource, RngDestin, RngCalc As Range
Dim i, j As Long
Dim n As Integer
Dim Tot1, Tot2, Cust As String
```

Recentemente, pesquisando na internet, verifiquei que algumas fontes dizem que este modo de declarar variáveis está equivocado, pois apenas a última variável é dimensionada pelo tipo declarado. Por exemplo: na linha `Dim i, j As Long`, apenas a variável `j` será dimensionada como `Long`, já a variável `i` estaria sendo dimensionada como a variável genérica `Variant`. Supostamente, a forma correta de declaração seria:

```
Dim RngSource As Range, RngDestin As Range, RngCalc As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim n As Integer
Dim Tot1 As String, Tot2 As String, Cust As String
```

Contudo, ainda acho fontes na internet que recomendam o modelo anterior para encurtar o tamanho do código.

Afinal: qual a forma correta?

Comment: Para VB.NET eu posso te garantir que esta afirmação é uma falácia, ou seja, todas as variáveis da linha recebem o tipo definido por último. Mas não posso garantir para VB Clássico (que é o seu caso), eu até procurei como executar algum código em VB6 ou algum compilador online, mas realmente não achei nada que ajudasse.

Comment: Jovem, VBA não se aplica somente a excel. Por favor, mantenha a pergunta sem esta tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa definir o tipo de cada variável, caso contrário o tipo da mesma somente será definido após a atribuição de um valor, assim como ocorre no javascript.

Com a função `VarType` é possível verificar isso:

```
Dim i, j As Long

Debug.Print VarType(i) 'Resultado: 0
Debug.Print VarType(j) 'Resultado: 3

i = "texto"
Debug.Print VarType(i) 'Resultado: 8
```

Com base na tabela disponibilizada pela própria Microsoft:

[image: VarType]

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263402(v=vs.60).aspx